# Webpack fails with babel has been moved to babel-core

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack

I've followed the solutions on stackoverflow posts posted by different developers. However, none of them helped fix the issue I'm encountering. Few of the things I did are

1. uninstall babel
2. install babel-core, babel-cli
3. upgraded to node v6.2.2
4. reinstall webpack
5. blew up node_modules and ran npm install again

All of the above never fixed this error

```
ERROR in The node API for `babel` has been moved to `babel-core`.
 @ (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:3333 1:10-24

ERROR in The node API for `babel` has been moved to `babel-core`.
 @ (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:3333 3:16-37

ERROR in The node API for `babel` has been moved to `babel-core`.
 @ (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:3333 2:13-37

ERROR in (webpack)/~/process/browser.js
Module build failed: Error: Couldn't find preset "react" relative to directory "/Users/admin/.nvm/versions/node/v6.0.0/lib/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/process"
    at /Users/admin/repos/ReactJSApps/react-es6-setup/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:395:17
    at Array.map (native)
.
.
.
webpack: bundle is now VALID.
```

Here is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "react-es6-setup",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^15.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^15.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.10.4",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.4",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.9.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.11.1"
  }
}
```

And webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  entry: './main.js',
  output: {
    path: './',
    filename: 'index.js'
  },
  devServer: {
    inline: true,
    port: 3333
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
        {
          test: /\.js$/,
          exclude: 'node_modules',
          loader: 'babel',
          query: {
            presets: [ 'es2015', 'react' ]
          }
        }
    ]
  }
}
```

and the dir listing of the node_modules

```
$ ls -l node_modules/ |grep react
drwxr-xr-x    6 admim  207825898    204 Jul  6 02:02 babel-helper-builder-react-jsx/
drwxr-xr-x    6 admim  207825898    204 Jul  6 02:02 babel-plugin-transform-react-display-name/
drwxr-xr-x    6 admim  207825898    204 Jul  6 02:02 babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx/
drwxr-xr-x    6 admim  207825898    204 Jul  6 02:02 babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx-self/
drwxr-xr-x    6 admim  207825898    204 Jul  6 02:02 babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx-source/
drwxr-xr-x    6 admim  207825898    204 Jul  6 02:02 babel-preset-react/
drwxr-xr-x    9 admim  207825898    306 Jul  6 02:03 react/
drwxr-xr-x    9 admim  207825898    306 Jul  6 02:03 react-dom/
```

Comment: I don't see webpack in your package.json, did you install it without npm, or globally?

Comment: I globally installed it. Here is what I did and it fixed it. I uninstalled it and didn't use -g anymore. I just added --save-dev. What's the difference?

Comment: My first thought was that you were using an old version of webpack, so I wanted to check the version in your package.json and noticed it wasn't there.  I'm not sure why it's working now, unless there was something wrong with the previous version you were using.  Glad it's fixed though!

Comment: Sounds like an older version on your global. Yeah it's best to use --save-dev for webpack, then setup an npm script to run: `"start": "node node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js"`

Comment: and the more confusing thing is that on my other projects, webpack is working fine. Now that I've uninstalled it globally, I'm not sure what's going to happen to my other apps :D

Comment: Thank you folks! I'll keep this in mind. I guess the lesson learned is, never install webpack globally.

Answer (score 8):

Having `loaders: 'babel-loader'` in `webpack.config.js` fixed the issue for me-

install these dependencies using npm

```
"babel-core": "^6.1.2",
"babel-loader": "^6.1.0",
"babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.1.2",
"babel-preset-es2015": "^6.1.2",
"babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.1.2",
"babel-runtime": "^5.8.0",
```

In `webpack.config.js` file, have this code:

```
const path = require('path');
module.exports = {
  entry: './src/main.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'dist.js',
    publicPath: "js"
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

First delete the `node_module` folder, Then

```
npm init
npm i webpack -S (Install Globally too)
npm i babel-loader babel-preset-es2015 babel-preset-react babel-core -S
npm i react react-dom -S`
```

Make sure that your webpack.config.js has:

```
loaders: [
    {
      test: /\.js$/,
      exclude: 'node_modules',
      loader : 'babel-loader',

...
```

then `run webpack -d`

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by changing my loader to `babel-loader` instead of `babel` in my webpack configuration.

```
module: {
    rules: [
        {
            ...
            loader: 'babel',
            ...
        },
    ],
},
```